# Is there any IDE compatible with VCL and C++?

Tags: import, ide, vcl, borland-c++

I'm (still) using Borland Turbo C++ 2006. Is there any (non-borland) IDE that can import and compile my (VCL-based) projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the VCL relies on extensions to the C++ language which are not available in any compiler other than those produced by Borland/Embarcadero.